# In an adic ring A, if the image is nilpotent, there exists I containing x

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $x$ be an element of an adic ring $A$, and $I$ be an ideal of definition such that the image of $x$ in $A/I$ is nilpotent, then there exists an ideal of definition $J$, which contains $x$.

I can't understand the proof. The proof is:
Let $I$ be an ideal of definition such that $x+I$ is nilpotent in $A/I$ and $n$ be a positive integer such that $x^n \in I$ .
Let $J=I+xA$. $J$ is an open ideal of $A$ (why is $J$ open? is it because it contains $I$ ?).
$J^n \subset I$.
The $I$-adic and $J$-adic topologies coincide, so $J$ is an ideal of definition (why?).

Comment: If $x^n \in I$ then $J=I+xA\supset I$ and $J^n \subset I$ so the natural map is surjective $\varprojlim A/I^m\to \varprojlim A/J^{m}= \varprojlim A/J^{nm}\to \varprojlim A/I^m$ ie. $\varprojlim A/J^m= \varprojlim A/I^m$. Is there anything else to show ?